# Moving Body Text out from a Heading in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-365

I am using Microsoft Word 365

I'm wondering if there is a way to move the body text out to the previous heading in word. This is what my document looks now:

[image]

I would like the text 'NEXT PARAGRAPH TEST TEXT' to not collapse under the 'Retrieving SV information' heading but to collapse under the 'SV Info & Orders' heading.

I have tried inserting a section break, but this prevents the text from collapsing at all. Is there any way to make this work, or am I out of luck?

Comment: Just use a different Style for the Header and another Style for the Body. Sections do not work for this.

Answer (score 0):

### Change the paragraph 'Retrieving SV information' to be also body text outline level.

See my page on [Outlining in Microsoft Word](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/outlining.htm) for more information.

The Outline level is a paragraph setting, usually incorporated in a paragraph style like the heading styles. The built-in heading styles must have the outline level set by Word but you can use a custom style.